# CMake finds Boost, but cannot include components on mingw-w64

Tags: c++, boost, mingw-w64

The error is:

```
fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp: No such file or directory
   21 | #include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>
```

I use mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

# cross compilers to use for C, C++ and Fortran
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gfortran)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)


# target environment on the build host system
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

# modify default behavior of FIND_XXX() commands
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)`
```

with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/include/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake  /path to project/
```

My CMakeLists.txt file contains

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
```

When I don't use mingw-w64, everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create `mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake` yourself, or is it something MSYS2 ships? You probably shouldn't have or use any libraries or compilers in `/usr`, but rather from `/mingw64` or `/ucrt64`, depending on your desired [compiler flavor](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/).

Comment: Are you actually using the found boost libraries in some way? Please show a [mre]